# Add dll reference, permission?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to asp.net and I am trying to use the framework SolidConverter. I did the installation and reference, however when running the application gives the following error

Failed to load C: \ Users \ Evandro \ AppData \ Local \ SolidDocuments \ SolidFramework \ Bin \ 8_0_3337_0 \ W32 \ SdAppSrv

SdAppSrv is a dll and is in a corret place.

The SolidFramework.dll unpacks several files in directory C: \ Users \ Evandro \ AppData \ Local \ SolidDocuments \ SolidFramework \ Bin \ 8_0_3337_0 \ W32 \

I contacted the support SolidConverter and told me that the problem was with access permissions, I added users NETWORK SERVICES, IIS_IUSRS with full access to the folder, any idea how to solve?

I use windows 7 64b and visual studio 12 and test .Net framework 4.5.50709 e .Net framework 4.0.3

I added permissions to the folder

[image: Permission folder]

[image: Error]

[image: DLL local]

Thanks,

Evandro

Comment: From the stack trace (please just copy and paste the text, it helps the search and mobile users) it looks like it's not an exception that .NET can't load a DLL, but an exception thrown from the library. Can't their support help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you added the DLL as a reference to your project itself. So your project knows nothing about it.

In VS2012 right-click the root of your site and choose "Add Reference".

Then in the popup, select "Browse" tab. Navigate to your DLL and add it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, yes I add dll reference in my project, dll is SolidFramework.dll, and solidframeword.dll unpacks and create all  files in directory C: \ Users \ Evandro \ AppData \ Local \ SolidDocuments \ SolidFramework \ Bin \ 8_0_3337_0 \ W32 \, SdAppSrv.dll is a file from solidframework.dll